# How to create a popup textbox when clicking a cell in Excel

Tags: excel, textbox, popup

I need to have a coding or function to create a popup textbox in Excel. From there, I could edit the text, add more text that I like. In every cell, I could add such textbox which will be popped up when I click on that cell.

I have used comments/data validation function in Excel but I need to have lengthy text and basic text format (bold, italic, underline). Thus, Comments or data validation could not help.

Thanks for your help in advance.

I am new in Excel

Answer (score 0):

If you just want textboxes and formatted text, try the text box (from Insert tab).

But if you want a pop-up textbox, triggered by clicking the button, then you should use the Form Control (in Developer tab). Youtube should have some videos on this matter.